# Ionic 2 : Local notification icon

Tags: javascript, typescript, notifications, ionic2

I use this plugin to have local notification : 
https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications/wiki/03.-Installation

I want to have a specific icon in my notification. It is located in my /www/assets/images/ folder.

I try this way but it doesn't work, I have a square icon with a bell :

```
public schedule() {
    cordova.plugins.notification.local.schedule({
      title: "New Message",
      message: "Hi, are you ready? We are waiting.",
      sound: null,
      at: new Date(new Date().getTime() + 5 * 1000),
      icon: 'file://assets/images/logo2.png'
    });
  }
```

Someone can show me the type of path I have to write ? I'm lost.

Comment: its probably `../assets/images/logo2.png`

Comment: No it doesn't work. :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution :

I create a new folder named "drawable" in /platforms/android/res/
I put my image in my new folder with name "ic_notifications.png" and "ic_notifications_small.png".

In my code I wrote

```
cordova.plugins.notification.local.schedule({
      id: 2,
      title: "Notification",
      message: "Retour à l'application",
      sound: null,
      at: new Date(new Date().getTime() + 5 * 1000),
      icon: 'ic_notifications',
      smallIcon: 'ic_notification_small'
    });
```

And it works !

Comment: It works but a gray color appears in the background of the app icon.

Comment: how to change the background-color of the icon of the local notifications

Answer (score 9):

For Local push notification of ionic 2 plugin you can set the icon like below. Here icon.png will be taking from the drawable folder in android. And you can configure ionic to copy the local image file to drawable folder by adding lines mentioned below in config file under android platform section.

```
<platform name="android">
<resource-file src="resources/android/icon/icon.png" target="res/drawable/icon.png"/>
</platform>
        

this.localNotifications.schedule({
          id: 1,
          title: data.title,
          text: data.body,
          data: data,
          icon: "res://icon.png",
          smallIcon:"res://icon.png"
        });
```

Comment: Copying like this, plus the icon has to be 72x72 pixels with a transparent background.

Comment: For newer Cordova versions (7+?), `target` should have the form `app/src/main/res/drawable/icon.png` (different base directory than before).

Answer (score 6):

If your only problem is with the notifications icons appearing correctly on Android, the following worked for me - take the ***drawable-xhdpi-icon*** icon (size **96x96**), rename it **icon.png** and place it in two places:

- /src/assets/img
- /platforms/android/res/drawable

The ***drawable*** folder is a new folder which can be created by copying ***platforms/android/res/mipmap-xhdpi*** to ***platforms/android/res/drawable*** manually or with the aid of a hook.
In your code, the **local** or **geofence** notification is referenced as follows:

```
smallIcon: 'res://icon',
icon: 'file://assets/img/icon.png'
```

If ***ionic cordova resources*** is part of the problem, you can do your own one-time setup by taking your largest icon and, with the help of a resizing tool such as resizeimage.net, create a set of icons for iOS and Android.
The  Excel here https://github.com/dovk/howto_resources-folder has a list of the sizes and names of the .png files to create. You then place them in their respective resources folder just like ***ionic cordova resources*** would have done - for example in ***resources/android/icon, resources/ios/splash*** and so on.
If you do so, then ***ionic cordova platform add android*** or ***ionic cordova platform add ios*** should not be used anymore, as this also does ***ionic cordova resources*** - What you need to do is ***cordova platform add*** (without the ***ionic*** in the beginning).

Answer (score 0):

in AndroidManifest.xml add following meta-data then it will work.

```
 <application
    android:name="xxxxxx"
        android:label="xxxxxx"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        
        >

       <meta-data
                android:name="your_apps_bundle_id.default_notification_icon"
                android:resource="@drawable/ic_notif" />

......
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        var teste = new NotificationImage { FilePath = "@Resources/drawable/IcoApp.png" };


        var notification = new NotificationRequest
        {
            Description = "Test Description",
            Title = "Notification!",
            ReturningData = "Dummy Data",
            Image = teste
        };
```

Comment: Code-only answer, should be avoided. Even if your code does solve the problem/question, you should add some explanation.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Answer (score -1):

Give image path as below without adding extension to the image file name
`LocalNotifications.schedule({
            id: 1,
            title: "Notification Title",
            text: "Notification Text",
            icon: 'assets://images/image_name'
          });`