# ionic - What is the correct way to change icon in local notifications plugin?

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm trying to use the native [local notifications plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/local-notifications/) and having troubles changing the default icon for the notification.

So far, I've used two phones to test this, both android devices: the first, Oreo (8.1.0) and the other one, Nougat (7.0). I'm using Ionic CLI 4.5.0, and I'm aware its wrapper is not compatible with the plugin, as stated in the plugin repository.

I've tried many paths for the icon URI, according to what [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42117124/ionic-2-local-notification-icon) suggested, but nothing seems to work.

In a provider, this is the relevant part of the code:

```
declare var cordova: any;
...
// inside a function that takes "id", "nome" and "tempo" as parameters:
cordova.plugins.notification.local.schedule({
    id: id,
    title: nome,
    text: "Sua atividade agendada, \"" + nome + "\", está prestes a começar!",
    at: new Date(tempo),
    foreground: true,
    icon: 'res://icone-notif.png',
    smallIcon: 'res://icone-notif-24.png'
});
```

And in my config.xml, I added these lines:

```
<platform name="android">
    ...
    <resource-file src="resources/android/icon/icone-notif-24.png" target="res/icone-notif-24.png" />
    <resource-file src="resources/android/icon/icone-notif.png" target="res/icone-notif.png" />
</platform>
```

(I've checked every file and they get placed in the "res" folder in my project correctly)

The notification icon should be shown as the images I saved in those folders, but what I get is just the default white square.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I struggled for a long time, and here is what I did to solve that:

My notification is declared as such:

```
const notification = {
    id: idNotif,
    text: this.getNotifText(notifs[0].type),
    trigger: {at: dateNotif},
    led: 'FF0000',
    smallIcon: 'res://ic_stat_notify.png',
    icon: 'res://icon.png',
    vibrate: true
};
this.localNotifications.schedule(notification);
```

In that code sample, notice that the links to these icons are prefixed with `res://`. These icons are actually located in the `platforms/android/app/src/main/res` folder, which is automatically generated when you compile your app (with `ionic cordova run android` for instance).

If you want the notifications to work, you should have the following folders in that `res` folder:

- drawable-mdpi
- drawable-hdpi
- drawable-xhdpi
- drawable-xxhdpi
- drawable-xxxhdpi

You also need the file `icon.png` directly in the folder `res`, as it is referenced as the `icon` parameter in the local notification declaration.

The folders correspond to the **different possible icon sizes in Android**, depending on pixel densities. You can find more about it in the [icon handbook](http://iconhandbook.co.uk/reference/chart/android/). When the notification will be triggered, the right size of icon will automatically be chosen among these 5 possible sizes.

Each of these folders must contain the file `ic_stat_notify.png`, which needs to be the icon in the right format:

- drawable-mdpi: 24x24
- drawable-hdpi: 36x36
- drawable-xhdpi: 48x48
- drawable-xxhdpi: 72x72
- drawable-xxxhdpi: 96x96
- icon.png: 96x96

#### Alright, but how do I put these in a folder that is generated only after compiling?

The answer is: by creating a **hook**.

Put these folders in a folder that you can access and that exists all the time in your app. Personally, I used `resources/android/icon`.

Then, create a hook to copy those files into the right folder everytime the app is compiled.

Here is my hook `icon_notif.js` (note: **it is heavily inspired by [this tutorial](https://leifwells.github.io/2016/05/30/setting-android-icons-with-local-notifications/)**):

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

var filestocopy = [];
var filestocopyAndroid = [
    {
        "resources/android/icon/drawable-mdpi/ic_stat_notify.png":
        "platforms/android/app/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/ic_stat_notify.png"
    },
    {
        "resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi/ic_stat_notify.png":
        "platforms/android/app/src/main/res/drawable-hdpi/ic_stat_notify.png"
    },
    {
        "resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi/ic_stat_notify.png":
        "platforms/android/app/src/main/res/drawable-xhdpi/ic_stat_notify.png"
    },
    {
        "resources/android/icon/drawable-xxhdpi/ic_stat_notify.png":
        "platforms/android/app/src/main/res/drawable-xxhdpi/ic_stat_notify.png"
    },
    {
        "resources/android/icon/drawable-xxxhdpi/ic_stat_notify.png":
        "platforms/android/app/src/main/res/drawable-xxxhdpi/ic_stat_notify.png"
    },
    {
        "resources/android/icon/icon.png":
        "platforms/android/app/src/main/res/icon.png"
    }
];

var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var rootdir = './';
var androiddir = path.join(rootdir, "platforms/android");
var iosdir = path.join(rootdir, "platforms/ios");

if(fs.existsSync(androiddir)) {
    filestocopy = filestocopyAndroid;
    console.log("Android platform file recognized");
} else if(fs.existsSync(iosdir)) {
    console.log("iOS platform file recognized");
    filestocopy = filestocopyiOS;
} else {
    console.log("Error: no Android or iOS platform file was recognized.");
    filestocopy = [];
}

console.log("~~~~ Start Copying Notification Status Icons");
filestocopy.forEach(function (obj) {
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(function (key) {
        var val = obj[key];
        var srcfile = path.join(rootdir, key);
        var destfile = path.join(rootdir, val);
        console.log("copying: " + srcfile);
        console.log("     to: " + destfile);
        var destdir = path.dirname(destfile);
        if(!fs.existsSync(destdir)) {
            fs.mkdirSync(destdir);
        }
        if (fs.existsSync(srcfile) && fs.existsSync(destdir)) {
            fs.createReadStream(srcfile).pipe(
                fs.createWriteStream(destfile));
        }
    });
});
console.log("~~~~ End Copying Notification Status Icons");
```

Basically, this script copies the right folders into the newly generated `platforms/android/app/src/main/res folder`.

As long as this hook runs properly, everything should work fine!

Comment: I didn't use the hook file you provided because I couldn't find a folder to place them in my project, so instead I used the config.xml like I was doing before but with the correct paths you posted. And I also resized the icon for each dpi to make sure it would work, and now it's done! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad I could help. :)

Comment: Thanks! saved me twice. This tool can help to generate images and folders: http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-notification.html

Comment: For anyone using cordova >= 7.0.0: I needed to replace `<icon density="xxx" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxx-icon.png" />` with `<resource-file src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxx-icon.png" target="app/src/main/res/drawable-xxx/icon.png" />` (I seriously don't know why `icon` should still be supported according to the docs, but for me the resources just weren't copied when running `cordova build android`)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone visiting this in 2023

[@Gustavo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8711272/gustavo) Mentions a good tool to generate the Icons [AndroidAssetStudio](http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-notification.html)

[@Reyedy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6346623/reyedy) Explains the concept. But to implement this in 2023 you can use this tool [Trapeze](https://trapeze.dev) by the Ionic team.

Using the Configuration File (yaml) in Trapeze

P.S `trapeze/android/res` would be a custom location in project root when you keep the files to be copied to the (android/ios project folder) i.e `android/app/src/main/res`

```yaml
platforms:
  android:
    copy:
      # Notification icon
      - src: ../trapeze/android/res/drawable-mdpi/ic_stat_logo.png
        dest: app/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/ic_stat_logo.png
      - src: ../trapeze/android/res/drawable-hdpi/ic_stat_logo.png
        dest: app/src/main/res/drawable-hdpi/ic_stat_logo.png
      - src: ../trapeze/android/res/drawable-xhdpi/ic_stat_logo.png
        dest: app/src/main/res/drawable-xhdpi/ic_stat_logo.png
      - src: ../trapeze/android/res/drawable-xxhdpi/ic_stat_logo.png
        dest: app/src/main/res/drawable-xxhdpi/ic_stat_logo.png
      - src: ../trapeze/android/res/drawable-xxxhdpi/ic_stat_logo.png
        dest: app/src/main/res/drawable-xxxhdpi/ic_stat_logo.png
```

According to [Capacitor Local Notification Docs](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/local-notifications)

```
import { CapacitorConfig } from '@capacitor/cli';

const config: CapacitorConfig = {
  plugins: {
    LocalNotifications: {
      smallIcon: "ic_stat_logo", // The value for this option should be the drawable resource ID, which is the filename without an extension. Only available for Android
      iconColor: "#488AFF",
    },
  },
};

export default config;
```